# INSERT OR REPLACE on SQLite not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table for storing contacts. Following is the query which is executed in onCreate. These queries are giving expected result in [sqliteonline.com](http://sqliteonline.com) . I don't know what is going wrong here.

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts (rowId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name VARCHAR(256),mobile VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE,email VARCHAR(64))
```

Using this code i am reading contact.

```
    val phones = activity.contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null)
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    val name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME))
                    var phone = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                    val contact = Contact()
                    contact.name = name
                    contact.mobile = phone

                    val query = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO $TABLE_NAME ($COL_NAME, $COL_MOBILE, $COL_EMAIL) \n" +
                            "  VALUES ('${contact.name}','${contact.mobile}','${contact.email}');"
                    val result = db.rawQuery(query, null)
                    Log.d("ContactManager" , "Query : $query")
                    result.close()
                }
                db.setTransactionSuccessful()
                phones.close()
```

I even tried this in the place of the query (this also not working)

```
            val query = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO $TABLE_NAME ($COL_ID,$COL_NAME, $COL_MOBILE, $COL_EMAIL) \n" +
                    "  VALUES ((select $COL_ID from $TABLE_NAME where $COL_MOBILE = '${contact.mobile}'),'${contact.name}','${contact.mobile}','${contact.email}');"
```

These are the queries are executed while doing insert or update.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Contacts (name, mobile, email) VALUES ('Police','100','');
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Contacts (name, mobile, email) VALUES ('Balance Info','111','');
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Contacts (name, mobile, email) VALUES ('Distress Number','112','');
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Contacts (name, mobile, email) VALUES ('Distress Number','112','');
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Contacts (name, mobile, email) VALUES ('Customer Care','121','');
```

Comment: any errors in logs ?

Comment: define not working ... also obviously you should try to use `SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict` with `CONFLICT_REPLACE` option instead rawQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `val result = db.rawQuery(query, null)` with `db.execSQL(query)`  
`rawQuery` is used to fetch rows not to execute update or insert/delete. 
Also remove `\n` from the sql statement. It is not syntactically wrong (I think) but it is not needed.  
Also since you use `db.setTransactionSuccessful()` you should also use at the beginning `db.beginTransaction()` and at the end `db.endTransaction()`

Comment: *rawQuery is used to fetch rows not to execute update or insert/delete* ... same as `execSQL` *`execSQL` - Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.*

Comment: @Selvin Just look again at your source. Is it the case that you read the comments for the below function?

Comment: it is the same methods ... anyway ... *Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.

**It has no means to return any data (such as the number of affected rows).  Instead, you're encouraged to use insert(String, String, ContentValues), update(String, ContentValues, String, String[]), et al, when possible.*** ... so yeah ... as always .. I had right anyway

Comment: Guess what ... INSERT returns row id ... so obviously it is *SQL statement that returns data* ... so `execSQL` should not be used ... please read the docs with understanding

Comment: @Selvin the method `db.insert` returns the id not the sql statement `INSERT`

Comment: Thank you so much. A simple mistake made me confused for long time.